# Test Login with credentials as superuser Django 1.9, Python 3.5

Tags: python, django, testing

I've been attempting to login as superuser to test-drive admin features with Django 1.9 and Python 3.5, but my login keeps failing.

Here's the test. It always returns false at the last assertion:

```
class TestAdmin(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
    def test_login(self):
        my_admin = User(username='user', email='user@email.com')
        my_admin.set_password('passphrase')
        my_admin.is_superuser=True
        my_admin.is_staff=True
        response = self.client.get('/admin/', follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTrue('Log in' in response.content.decode('utf-8'))
        loginresponse = self.client.login(username='user', email='user@email.com',
                                          password='passphrase')
        self.assertTrue(loginresponse)
```

Comment: I think you should do `my_admin.save()`

Comment: Problem fixed. 
I wish I could give the bounty to you.
Also, apparently it's `.is_staff=True` and not `.is_superuser=True` which enables admin login (I eliminated them one by one after it worked), which is I suppose counter-intuitive--I would think the superuser could do anything.

Comment: Thanks @Jordon Birk. If you agree I could add my comment as a response, and perhaps so you can do that. Thanks again, the most important is that you solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do `my_admin.save()`

Your `.is_staff=True` user needs to be saved into the user "database" that's created at the runtime of the test. The permissions should be fine with the following script:

```
class TestAdmin(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.my_admin = User(username='user', is_staff=True)
        my_admin.set_password('passphrase') # can't set above because of hashing
        my_admin.save() # needed to save to temporary test db
        response = self.client.get('/admin/', follow=True)
        loginresponse = self.client.login(username='user',password='passphrase')
        self.assertTrue(loginresponse) # should now return "true"
```